# God's autobiography?

Tags: story-identification

This is story I read, in Danish, perhaps 30 years ago; I thought it was hilarious back then, and I wonder if I still would now, and I would like to read it in the original language (English, no doubt).

The plot was a lighthearted take on what God would write in his autobiography; nothing much to say other than that, really.

Comment: God or [King David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_Knows_(novel))?

Comment: Definitely God.

Comment: Quite a common theme; https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/710582.The_Life_of_God

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quick google search came up with [God: The Ultimate Autobiography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0881622923).

Originally published in 1988.

From a review on Amazon:

> The "author" of this irreverent, good-natured romp is identified as
>   "God, The Author of All Creation, with Jeremy Pascall, holy ghost."
>   Covering mainly the high points of the Old Testament, the Author tells
>   us that Adam and Eve were created primarily to take care of Eden, "a
>   little piece of Heaven on Earth" and "the first ever Garden Center."
>   The begetting part got a bit out of hand occasionally, He admits,
>   larking His way through chapters on Noah and Sodom and Gomorrah. In
>   fact, He thinks the procreative act "too complicated . . .
>   uncomfortable . . . and extremely undignified. . . . Personally, I
>   prefer a nice cup of tea." And He confesses that He turns malcontents
>   into cacti, which is how He transformed his holy ghost writer (see
>   Footnote 61). British novelist Pascall obviously did not intend this
>   sunny little book for fundamentalists or those of any faith who take
>   their religion seriously. Illustrated with 40 rather uninspiring
>   cartoons, the book also contains a Bibleography (sic) that lists the
>   soon-to-be-discovered Red Sea Scrolls and The Noah Letters, "written
>   by Noah and his wife Norah to The Author"; an Addenda (sic): Anchovy,
>   the use of as a cure for bunions. . . . ; an Eratta (sic): "There are
>   no eratta as The Author does not make mistakes"; and an Erratum:
>   "Eratta should be spelt errata. The Publisher apologizes for this
>   error."

Comment: There was a companion book, Satan: The Hiss-and-tell Memoirs, that had all the same sort of errata jokes. It's the first place I remember seeing the index include the joke, "Redundant: see redundant"